# How to set user profile Id in a trigger test

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am writing a trigger test class for a trigger that inserts a new task when the current task is saved. In the trigger I only want it to fire when the current user has a certain profile. Because of this, I am unable to get past that validation in testing since I am logged in as system administrator. is there a way to bypass this in the trigger test code?

Answer (score 2):

There is this example in the [Using the runAs Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) documentation that shows how to switch profile in a test:

```
@isTest
private class TestRunAs {

    @isTest       
    static void testTriggerUsingRunAs() {

        // Create a unique UserName
        String uniqueUserName = 'user' + DateTime.now().getTime() + '@org.com';

        // Pick the Profile you want to test under here
        String profileName = 'Standard User';
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = :profileName];

        // Create a User object that uses that Profile
        User u = new User(
            UserName = uniqueUserName,
            ProfileId = p.Id,
            Alias = 'standt',
            Email = 'user@org.com',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LastName = 'Testing',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles'
        );

        System.runAs(u) {
            // Add your trigger test code here
            System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
            System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId());
        }
    }
}
```

(I've changed this a bit for the context of your question.)

Comment: Amazing, thank you.